# Stop Angular HTTP request without using unsubcribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a music player but when the user skips a song it should stop the current download of a song and move ahead to the next one. I am using an async angular http function that resolves into a promise. I can not use subscribe() or unsubcribe() because that will just break the functionality

This is my code:

```
private async downloadSong(track: Track): Promise<string> {
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.request))
      console.log(this.request) // Returns: Response {_body: Blob, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}

    this._downloadingSong = true;
    this.request = await this.http.get(track.source, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}).toPromise();
    this._downloadingSong = false;
    return URL.createObjectURL(this.request.blob());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"...stop the current download.."*? Do you mean in a currently playing source? Or do you mean to cancel the current request for the "next track" when the method gets fired again? For the latter i.e "Fast clicks" resulting in `this.http.get(track.source, ....` being cancelled if another "click" event came in before the response.

Comment: Stop the current download if the track has been skipped so a 'click' on a button

Answer (score 0):

You should use [takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) operator to stop observable